# ZED VO vs Rtabmap VO

Tags: slam, navigation, visual-odometry, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ZED cameras and also running Rtabmap. Both systems have visual odom available. What are the pros and cons of using ZED VO instead of rtabmap? Do I get gains from using one over the other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351086/zed-vo-vs-rtabmap-vo/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ZED VO is likely much tuned for the ZED than what one will accomplish with the more generic Rtabmap VO, I recall having decent results with the ZED VO node.

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0